# Can any one please give me clear information about Indexes in App Engine Data store with example.?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to search Users datastore with Email id. The Users datastore have more than 1000 records. Its nearly taking 9sec for the output. I Think indexing with be helpful for this problem. So.. please help me.

Comment: post your code that takes 9 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [AppStats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) to get a better view into where the time is going.

[Here's some documentation on indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html). All queries must be served by an index, though, so there's no chance that you could add an index and improve performance.